# (Wordpress) User Registered On Current Month

Tags: wordpress

How to made function to count total user registered on Wordpress site with just specific roles (eg: manager) and just users that registered current month only?

Example code, it will output user registered all time, I want it just ouput user registered on current month only.

```
function totalusertoday() {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE user_status = 0";
    return $wpdb->get_var($query);
}

echo 'Total User Today: ' . totalusertoday();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I'm just put filter for current month and year on user registered. And I've made simple code for this. Here is example code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$date = getdate();

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users WHERE MONTH(user_registered) = $date[mon] AND YEAR(user_registered) = $date[year]" );
echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Database Model:
http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/97/WP3.8-ERD.png

To count all new users from this month, simply select all Users with registred Timestamp > then 1. day of this month.

To get only users with a specific role you have to select the user and the wp_usermeta, in wp_usermeta is a row called wp_capabilities.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/name-of-database-fields-for-user-rolespermissions

Basically it's just a bit of sql query.